Problem connection from spring boot to mongodb in docker-container

I have started mongodb container from docker-compose file

services:
  mongo:
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=mydatabase
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
      - '27018:27018'
      - '27019:27019'
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo-js:ro
      - ./mongo/data:/data/db   

this script should be executed on startup
init-mongo.js
print("Started-adding-the-users.");
   
db=db.getSiblingDB()('admin');
    
use admin;   
    
db.createUser({
    user: "root",
    pwd: "password",
    roles: [
        {
            role: 'readWrite',
            db: 'admin',
        },
        {
            role: 'readWrite',
            db: 'mydatabase',
        }
    ],
});
    
db=db.getSiblingDB()('mydatabase');
    
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "db_user",
        pwd: "pass123",
        roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "mydatabase" }, "readWriteAnyDatabase" ]
    }
);
    
db.createCollection('init');

After that my spring boot application is trying to connect to mongo with properties
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/
spring.data.mongodb.database=mydatabase
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=password

I am getting error:
Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'Command update requires authentication'
why it happenning?

Did you start up your mongo service at least once before the init-mongo.js? If yes, then the database already exists so it won't keep re-executing the init files; that only happens once when the service is started up and no db dir exists. Delete the /mongo/data dir on your machine, which is mapped to the db dir.
